# Error importing image dataset in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, utf-8, tensorflow-datasets

I get an error when trying to import a dataset into tensor flow. I have trained other models with tensor flow so I am pretty sure that tensor flow works just fine. Does anyone know the cause of this error? and please if can tell me how to fix it I am using this dataset https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/atharvataras/dog-breeds-images

```
dataset=keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(".\dataset",seed=123,label_mode='categorical',image_size=(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE),batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

and I get this error

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 dataset=keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(".\dataset",seed=123,label_mode='categorical',image_size=(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE),batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

File c:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\image_dataset.py:210, in image_dataset_from_directory(directory, labels, label_mode, class_names, color_mode, batch_size, image_size, shuffle, seed, validation_split, subset, interpolation, follow_links, crop_to_aspect_ratio, **kwargs)
    208 if seed is None:
    209     seed = np.random.randint(1e6)
--> 210 image_paths, labels, class_names = dataset_utils.index_directory(
    211     directory,
    212     labels,
    213     formats=ALLOWLIST_FORMATS,
    214     class_names=class_names,
    215     shuffle=shuffle,
    216     seed=seed,
    217     follow_links=follow_links,
    218 )
    220 if label_mode == "binary" and len(class_names) != 2:
    221     raise ValueError(
    222         'When passing `label_mode="binary"`, there must be exactly 2 '
    223         f"class_names. Received: class_names={class_names}"
    224     )

File c:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\dataset_utils.py:543, in index_directory(directory, labels, formats, class_names, shuffle, seed, follow_links)
    541 subdirs = []
...
--> 703   return _pywrap_file_io.IsDirectory(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
    704 except errors.OpError:
    705   return False

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 114: invalid start byte
```

the entire error output

```html
{
    "name": "UnicodeDecodeError",
    "message": "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 114: invalid start byte",
    "stack": "\u001b[1;31m---------------------------------------------------------------------------\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;31mUnicodeDecodeError\u001b[0m                        Traceback (most recent call last)\nCell \u001b[1;32mIn[7], line 1\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m----> 1\u001b[0m dataset\u001b[39m=\u001b[39mkeras\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mutils\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mimage_dataset_from_directory(\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m\\\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39mdataset\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m,seed\u001b[39m=\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m123\u001b[39;49m,label_mode\u001b[39m=\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m'\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39mcategorical\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m'\u001b[39;49m,image_size\u001b[39m=\u001b[39;49m(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE),batch_size\u001b[39m=\u001b[39;49mBATCH_SIZE)\n\nFile \u001b[1;32mc:\\Users\\harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\utils\\image_dataset.py:210\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mimage_dataset_from_directory\u001b[1;34m(directory, labels, label_mode, class_names, color_mode, batch_size, image_size, shuffle, seed, validation_split, subset, interpolation, follow_links, crop_to_aspect_ratio, **kwargs)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    208\u001b[0m \u001b[39mif\u001b[39;00m seed \u001b[39mis\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mNone\u001b[39;00m:\n\u001b[0;32m    209\u001b[0m     seed \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m np\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mrandom\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mrandint(\u001b[39m1e6\u001b[39m)\n\u001b[1;32m--> 210\u001b[0m image_paths, labels, class_names \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m dataset_utils\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mindex_directory(\n\u001b[0;32m    211\u001b[0m     directory,\n\u001b[0;32m    212\u001b[0m     labels,\n\u001b[0;32m    213\u001b[0m     formats\u001b[39m=\u001b[39;49mALLOWLIST_FORMATS,\n\u001b[0;32m    214\u001b[0m     class_names\u001b[39m=\u001b[39;49mclass_names,\n\u001b[0;32m    215\u001b[0m     shuffle\u001b[39m=\u001b[39;49mshuffle,\n\u001b[0;32m    216\u001b[0m     seed\u001b[39m=\u001b[39;49mseed,\n\u001b[0;32m    217\u001b[0m     follow_links\u001b[39m=\u001b[39;49mfollow_links,\n\u001b[0;32m    218\u001b[0m )\n\u001b[0;32m    220\u001b[0m \u001b[39mif\u001b[39;00m label_mode \u001b[39m==\u001b[39m \u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[39mbinary\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m \u001b[39mand\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mlen\u001b[39m(class_names) \u001b[39m!=\u001b[39m \u001b[39m2\u001b[39m:\n\u001b[0;32m    221\u001b[0m     \u001b[39mraise\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mValueError\u001b[39;00m(\n\u001b[0;32m    222\u001b[0m         \u001b[39m'\u001b[39m\u001b[39mWhen passing `label_mode=\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[39mbinary\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[39m`, there must be exactly 2 \u001b[39m\u001b[39m'\u001b[39m\n\u001b[0;32m    223\u001b[0m         \u001b[39mf\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[39mclass_names. Received: class_names=\u001b[39m\u001b[39m{\u001b[39;00mclass_names\u001b[39m}\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m\n\u001b[0;32m    224\u001b[0m     )\n\nFile \u001b[1;32mc:\\Users\\harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\utils\\dataset_utils.py:543\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mindex_directory\u001b[1;34m(directory, labels, formats, class_names, shuffle, seed, follow_links)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    541\u001b[0m subdirs \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m []\n\u001b[0;32m    542\u001b[0m \u001b[39mfor\u001b[39;00m subdir \u001b[39min\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39msorted\u001b[39m(tf\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mio\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mgfile\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mlistdir(directory)):\n\u001b[1;32m--> 543\u001b[0m     \u001b[39mif\u001b[39;00m tf\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mio\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mgfile\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49misdir(tf\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mio\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mgfile\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mjoin(directory, subdir)):\n\u001b[0;32m    544\u001b[0m         \u001b[39mif\u001b[39;00m subdir\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mendswith(\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[39m/\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m):\n\u001b[0;32m    545\u001b[0m             subdir \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m subdir[:\u001b[39m-\u001b[39m\u001b[39m1\u001b[39m]\n\nFile \u001b[1;32mc:\\Users\\harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\lib\\io\\file_io.py:703\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mis_directory_v2\u001b[1;34m(path)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    694\u001b[0m \u001b[39m\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\"\"Returns whether the path is a directory or not.\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[0;32m    695\u001b[0m \n\u001b[0;32m    696\u001b[0m \u001b[39mArgs:\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m   (...)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    700\u001b[0m \u001b[39m  True, if the path is a directory; False otherwise\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[0;32m    701\u001b[0m \u001b[39m\"\"\"\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[0;32m    702\u001b[0m \u001b[39mtry\u001b[39;00m:\n\u001b[1;32m--> 703\u001b[0m   \u001b[39mreturn\u001b[39;00m _pywrap_file_io\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mIsDirectory(compat\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mpath_to_bytes(path))\n\u001b[0;32m    704\u001b[0m \u001b[39mexcept\u001b[39;00m errors\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mOpError:\n\u001b[0;32m    705\u001b[0m   \u001b[39mreturn\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mFalse\u001b[39;00m\n\n\u001b[1;31mUnicodeDecodeError\u001b[0m: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 114: invalid start byte"
}
```

I am fairly new to this any help would me much appreciated.

I tried looking for others who had a similar problem. The only thing I could find was people having the same error while importing csv and they usually fixed it by changing the encoding type from UTF-8 to something else but I don't think we can do it while using keras.preprocessing and if we can please tell me how to do it and how to find out what format would work with this dataset.

Comment: What is the extension of your dataset?

Comment: Dataset contains. jpg images

Comment: Hi @Harshaditya sharma. Please provide us some more details like which tensorflow version you have installed in your system and the platform details like (OS or Google colab/Jupyter notebook) to understand the issue.

Comment: @TFer2 I have tensorflow version 2.12.0. I am currently using python 3.11 on windows 11 but I have also tried it out with python 3.10.6 and gotten the same error and also I am running tensorflow on cpu.

Comment: Do u got the answer bro, I am also facing the same issue ...