# how to solve tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory invalid continuation byte error?

Tags: windows, tensorflow, ubuntu, keras, dataset

I had a python venv on ubuntu 20.04 and there i was using tensorflow to train my model. There was a folder named Persona and it has 5 subfolders as classes. each subfolder contains image files and some file names are Arabic and Farsi. there were no problem There and everything was fine until i migrate all those files to another device which it's OS is windows11. After setting up my environment and everything when i tried to run my code i got this error:

```
return _pywrap_file_io.IsDirectory(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 49: invalid continuation byte
```

the error occurs on second line of following code which i import model data using Keras:

```
image_path = 'D:\\Desktop\\tfmm\\Personas\\'
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    image_path,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
    class_names=None,
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(256, 256),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='training',
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
    crop_to_aspect_ratio=False
)
```

any help would be appreciated.

I searched on google and github to find the reason and the solution with no luck. i also found this question on stackoverflow with no acceptable answer [error-importing-image-dataset-in-tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76020238/error-importing-image-dataset-in-tensorflow)
I solved the problem by renaming all my image files to latin based encoding but this would be painfull when i need to keep original file names.